# Read excel file without opening it in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I’ve used earlier versions of VB years ago (large access database), new to VB.net 2022.
I’m trying to read in a single sheet from excel I’ve barrowed this snippet from:
Net-informations.com
http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_2007_open_file.htm
I've added the Microsoft Excel12.0 Object Library.

This code is in a button click event

```
strFileName = "F:\DarPlr\DlrData.xlsx"

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("strFileName") <<<<<<<exception thrown here
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    'display the cells value B2
    MsgBox(xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2).value)
    'edit the cell with new value
    'xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2) = "http://vb.net-informations.com"
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
```

I get this exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[image]

I've tried all the examples That I could find, all had errors of one type or another, I tried working through the errors but failed. I'm overlooking something but I don't know what.
Thanks in advance
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open the Excel file using the string "strFileName" instead of using the variable strFileName.

```
strFileName = "F:\DarPlr\DlrData.xlsx"

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName) '<<<<<< use variable strFileName instead of the string "strFileName"
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
'display the cells value B2
MsgBox(xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2).value)
'edit the cell with new value
'xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2) = "http://vb.net-informations.com"
xlWorkBook.Close()
xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried it @Dave?